# Conflict in React using font-awesome icons

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

Good evening everyone. I have som problem with React using font awesome icons. I want to import 3 circles from font awesome, 2 should be always empty/regular and one full/solid. My problem is that when I import it as I did I get error because that faCircle is already deefined.
How can I use solid and regular icons with same names?

```
import React from "react";
import MotionLeft from '../../Components/MotionLeft';
import {SectionStyled, StyleRow } from './styles';

//Font Awesome
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import {faEnvelope, faCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import {faCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';


const SignUp = () =>{
  
    
    return (

            <StyleRow >
                <MotionLeft/>
                <SectionStyled>
                <div class="right">
                    <div class="header">
                        <p>Already have an account?</p>
                        <button>Sign In</button>
                    </div>
                    <main>
                        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                        <div class="name">
                            <FontAwesomeIcon className="i" icon={faEnvelope} size = '1x'/>                           
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email"/>
                        </div>
                    </main>
                    <button class="signup">Sign Up</button>
                    <div className="progress-dots">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="i" icon={faCircle} size = '1x'/>  
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="i" icon={faCircle} size = '1x'/> 
                        <FontAwesomeIcon className="i" icon={faCircle} size = '1x'/> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
                </SectionStyled>
            </StyleRow>
        )
};

export default SignUp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rename one of the names of the conflicting icons with `as`, so for example, I took the one form `@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons` and renamed it as follows:

```
import {faCircle as faCircleRegular} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';
```

Later, when you'll reference the icon, use its new name:

```
 <FontAwesomeIcon className="i" icon={faCircleRegular} size = '1x'/>
```

This should solve the conflict issue. You can do it for any icon as you choose, I just randomly selected one.

Answer (score 0):

[This link should help](http://eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZmM1MTdlODgxYWFkZTQ0ZDA4ODUzZDYiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDY3NTI1OTcsImV4cCI6MTYwNjgzODk5N30.v-X-CpLGWxW7uLbB5nItNI1HvCjlVBABnY9TD_l7k_g)

You can import them as a different name

`import {faCircle as faRegCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons';`

Comment: @Michaela Sure, no problem : )